# Rename WordPress menu elements

Tags: wordpress

I have a list of pages generated using the code 'wp_list_pages'.

WordPress adds a lot of classes to my menu including

I'd like to rename 'page_item' - how do I do this?

Comment: Please include your code. Please show how you're currently getting the data, how it's appearing, and how it should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the appropraite filter, `nav_menu_css_class`. If you need an example, look at how roots starter theme does it: https://github.com/roots/roots/blob/master/lib/nav.php